# GIT pull from forked repository but both have advanced

Tags: git

I have a git repository having a branch say V1.
I have advanced its commits say c1.1->c1.2->c1.3, but then i have forked from c1.2 by name V2 as i need to maintain separate branch from c1.2.
I have added few/many commits say c2.1->c2.2->c2.3.
In mean time V1 advanced to c1.3->c1.4->c1.5.
Now at this point i want to add changes done in V2 branch in V1 branch but not affecting the changes done in V1.

I guess i can do it by create V2 branch from c1.2 commit then do 
git pull origin V2 --rebase

My question are as follows.

1. Will the above command run successfully without tampering any commits from V1 and V2.
2. What if i have changed same file but different part of code in both versions?
3. What if i have changed same file and same code in both version?
4. What if above two incident occurs together for same file?
5. Will there be any conflicts in above 3 points? if yes how to solve it? if no then why?
6. What happens to the commit messages

I do not want to get into deep insight of git. Simple layman answers expected but technical details also welcome.

Also when i tried to do git diff V2 from V1 branch i could see difference between V1 and V2 few additions and few removals.
Then from V1 i did git pull origin V2 and again did git diff V2 , i could see same difference again with few more difference.
Is this correct behaviour as i suspect it not because there should be no difference or only the extra difference.?

Comment: Can't you just cherry-pick the commits from V2 that you want?

Comment: I want to add every change and it can be n numbers to do cherry pick hence avoiding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two basic ways to do this in git are :

- merge V2 into V1 :

  ```
  git checkout V1
  git merge V2
  ```
- rebase V2 on top of V1 :

  ```
  git checkout V2
  git rebase V1
  ```

If git detects any file modified on both sides, where the diff is not exactly the same on both sides, it will stop before committing anything, and will let you inspect the content of said files.

This is what is called a *conflict*, and you can find some guides on choosing what version of each modified block you want to keep.

A starting point is : if such a thing occur, run the command `git mergetool`.
`git` will open your default diff tool in a 3 pane mode, where you can compare both versions of the file (left and right), and build the version you want to keep in the middle.

---

*Some explanations about what gets displayed in git mergetool :*

Let's say your history looks like this :

```
*--*--X--*--*--*--A <- branch V1
       \
        Y--Z--B <- branch V2
```

- If you **merge** `V2` into `V1` :

  ```
  git checkout V1
  git merge V2
  ```

  and get a conflict,
  when you open `git mergetool` :

  - the left pane (`LOCAL`) will be `V1`'s version of the file
  - the right pane (`REMOTE`) will be `V2`'s version of the file
  - the middle pane (`BASE`) will be : the version of the file at `X`
    `X` is the most recent commit which is an ancestor of both `V1` and `V2`
- If you **rebase** `V2` onto `V1` :

  ```
  git checkout V2
  git rebase V1
  ```

  *a quick reminder of git rebase :*

  git looks for the commits which are on `V2` and not already on `V1` (in our diagram, these commits would be `Y`, `Z` and `B`), and "replay" `Y` on top of `V1`, then `Z` on top of this last commit, then `B` on top of this last commit.

  *conflicts during a git rebase :*

  A conflict may occur when replaying `Y`, or when replaying `Z`, or when replaying `B`.

  At each step, the "base commit" will be the replayed commit's parent :

  - if a conflict occurs when replaying `Y`, the base commit will be `X`
  - if a conflict occurs when replaying `Z`, the base commit will be `Y`
  - if a conflict occurs when replaying `B`, the base commit will be `Z`

  *what gets displayed in git mergetool :*

  When you open `git mergetool` :

  - the left pane (`LOCAL`) will be `V1`'s version of the file
  - the right pane (`REMOTE`) will `replayed commit`'s version of the file, which depends on the step which triggered the conflict
  - the middle pane (`BASE`) will be `base commit`'s version of the file, which depends on the step which triggered the conflict

Comment: git checkout V2
git rebase V1  

In above two commands will V1 get what V2 has or viceversa as we are in V2 branch i assume V2 will get updated with V1?

Comment: Once rebase is done you can merge V2 to V1 to get changes done in V2 to V1

Comment: i am using mergetool
i have three panes local, remote and nameless.
In our case local will be V1 remote will be V2 and nameless is ?? 
I have different changes in all these panes.

Comment: middle pane is *base* -- I'll add this to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The response for your set of qsns,

1. Commits will never be tampered. Every commit is stored in the version carried over while merging.
2. The file will be auto merged with no conflicts if same line conflicts don't occur
3. Then there will be conflict, you have to manually resolve this conflict and commit these files.

For other questions below explanation should help.

`git Rebase` is correct behaviour and it rewrites the project history by creating brand new commits for each commit in the original branch. 
This helps in clean up the messy history if you have similar commits in same files. One thing is you can't track when changes were incorporated into feature.

```
Git checkout v2
Git rebase -i V1
```

This helps in interactive rebasing where you can alter commits accordingly.